Problem about inner regularity
Consider $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ a $\sigma$-finite measure space. So there is a partition $\{X_n\}$ of $X$ of measurable sets such that $\mu(X_n)<+\infty$. Consider $(\gamma_n)$ a sequence of strictly positive real numbers such that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\gamma_n\mu(X_n)=1$, and define $$\mu'(E):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\gamma_n\mu(E\cap X_n)$$
for every $E\in\Sigma$. It is clear that $\mu'$ is a probability measure. I want to prove the following thing: if $\mathcal{K}\subseteq\mathcal{P}(X)$ is such that $\mu(E)=\sup\{\mu(K) \, | \, K\in\mathcal{K},\ K\subseteq E\}$, then the same property holds also for $\mu'$, i.e. $\mu'(E)=\sup\{\mu'(K) \, | \, K\in\mathcal{K},\ K\subseteq E\}$ (the two previous equalities are valid for every $E\in\Sigma$). We can suppose that $\mathcal{K}$ is closed with respect to finite unions and countable intersection, if it's necessary.
Clearly we have that $\mu'(E)\ge\sup\{\mu'(K) \, | \, K\in\mathcal{K},\ K\subseteq E\}$ since $\mu'(E)\ge\mu'(K)$ for every $K\subseteq E$ by monotonicity of $\mu'$. How can I show the other inequality?

You can reduce the problem to showing that this holds for $\sum_{n=0}^N\gamma_n\mu(\cdot\cap X_n)$ for all $N$.

Consider arbitrary $E \in \Sigma$ and $\varepsilon > 0$. We find $K \in \mathcal K$ such that $K \subset E$ and $\mu'(E) \le \mu'(K) + \varepsilon$.
Let $Y_n$ denote the set $\cup_{k = 1}^n X_k$ and let $\delta_n = \max\{\gamma_1,\dots,\gamma_n\}$.
At first find $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $\mu'(E) \le \mu'(E \cap Y_n) + \varepsilon /2$. Next find $K \in \mathcal K$ such that $K \subset E \cap Y_n$ and $\mu(E \cap Y_n) \le \mu(K) + \varepsilon/(2 n \delta_n)$. Then, clearly, for all $j = 1, \dots, n$ we have $$\mu(E \cap X_j) = \mu(K \cap X_j) + \mu((E \setminus K) \cap X_j) \le  \mu(K \cap X_j) + \mu((E \setminus K) \cap Y_n) = $$
$$
\mu(K \cap X_j) + \mu(E \cap Y_n) - \mu(K) \le \mu(K \cap X_j) + \varepsilon/(2 n \delta_n).
$$
From this we conclude that $\gamma_j\mu(E \cap X_j) \le \gamma_j \mu(K \cap X_j) + \varepsilon / (2n)$. Summation for $j = 1, \dots, n$ yields $\mu'(E \cap Y_n) \le \mu'(K) + \varepsilon/2$ and, therefore, $\mu'(E) \le \mu'(K) + \varepsilon$.
